# Error Create New Web Application

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I need your help, there are error when I create new web application in our sharepoint consolidation.

[image]

Comment: Using correlation ID you can find proper error from logs.

Comment: I have do that.
Form the correlation ID I found this detail :

Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Claims Authentication
Level    : High
EventID  : fsq7
Message  : Request for security token failed with exception: System.DllNotFound

What should I do? 
Area     : SharePoint Foundation
Category : Claims Authentication
Level    : High
EventID  : fsq7
Message  : Request for security token failed with exception: System.DllNotFound

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things make sure:

- SharePoint Admin services is running on all servers in farm
- SharePoint Timer Services also running
- Make Sure Security Token Services is up
- Reset IIS on all server.
- Restart Timer and admin jobs

Also check this one https://onetidbit.wordpress.com/2010/10/01/solved-unable-to-create-or-delete-new-web-application-in-central-administration-in-sharepoint-2010/